# Вставить перевод строки в ячейке Excel

Tags: php, phpexcel

Пытаюсь взять значение из ячейки, вставить вместо запятых перевод строки в ячейке, вернуть обратно.

Получаем текст в ячейке А1

```
$ltr='A1';
$vle=$spreadsheet->getActiveSheet()->getCell($ltr);
```

Далее ищу запятые и меняю на \n.

```
$t=explode(', ', $vle);
if (count($t)>1) $vle=implode('\n', $t);
```

Возвращаю обратно, пытаюсь заменить \n. В документации [и тут](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5960242/how-to-make-new-lines-in-a-cell-using-phpexcel?rq=1) это работает. Но у меня при таком порядке действий - нет.

```
> $spreadsheet->getActiveSheet()->getCell($ltr)->setValue($vle);
> $spreadsheet->getActiveSheet()->getStyle($ltr)->getAlignment()->setWrapText(true);
```

Пытаюсь добиться следующего. Слева \n добавил сразу же для наглядности. Но оно там сразу или нет - по факту ничего не меняет. Не работает.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Также пробовал использовать char(10). Но тут странное происходит. Например, если попробовать вставить в ячейку `="hello"&char(10)&"world"`, то вставится всё до второго &. Т.е. вставится только `="hello"&char(10)`

Помогите, разобраться, пожалуйста. Можно сказать все сложности решил, а осталось вот это. И не могу никак сдвинуться с мёртвой точки.

Comment: не всё читал....но.... фишка с переводом каретки и вообще с управляющими символами в том, что надо их писать не в одинарных кавычках, а в двойных. `$vle=implode("\n", $t);`  Потому что обработка строк в одинарных и двойных - различна.

Comment: заработало!!!!!!))) Спасибо огромное!!! Оформите ответ ваш) Я вам отмечу плюсом

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В документации в разделе **[строки](http://php.net/manual/ru/language.types.string.php#language.types.string)** можно почитать про **[одинарные кавычки](http://php.net/manual/ru/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.single)** и **[двойные кавычки](http://php.net/manual/ru/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.double)** (еще про heredoc и nowdoc, но сейчас это не важно). Советую ознакомиться с описанием и особенно с их отличием между собой.

Там же можно увидеть описание и замечание в разделе **одинарных кавычек**:

> Чтобы использовать одинарную кавычку внутри строки, проэкранируйте ее обратным слешем (). Если необходимо написать сам обратный слеш, продублируйте его (\). Все остальные случаи применения обратного слеша будут интерпретированы как обычные символы: **это означает, что если вы попытаетесь использовать другие управляющие последовательности, такие как \r или \n, они будут выведены как есть вместо какого-либо особого поведения**.
>
> **Замечание**: В отличие от синтаксиса двойных кавычек и heredoc, переменные и управляющие последовательности для специальных символов, заключенных в одинарные кавычки, не обрабатываются.

И в разделе **двойных кавычек**:

> Если строка заключена в двойные кавычки ("), PHP распознает управляющие последовательности специальных символов.

Из этого можно сделать вывод, что вам нужно писать не так:

```
$vle = implode('\n', $t);
```

а вот так:

```
$vle = implode("\n", $t);
```